# Setting Value Html Attribute For Html.TextBox (MVC 1.0)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I'm creating an Html TextBox via HtmlHelper and I can't get the value attribute set. I've tried both of the lines below and I have also googled but cannot find a solution:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("name", null, new { @class = "textbox", value = "hi" }) %>
<%= Html.TextBox("name", null, new { @class = "textbox", @value = "hi" }) %>
```

Both lines return an input element with value=""

What am I missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The value is the second parameter of the Html.TextBox method :

```
<%= Html.TextBox("name", "hi", new { @class = "textbox" }) %>
```

should work